# Required parameter is missing: grant_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api

I am trying to authenticate google api in ruby. I got code parameter successfully. But I couldn't get access token using code params.i am passing following parameter to get access token

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=4/HttxxNNyD8RU-emkYJufAM2&client_id=103xxxxxx-t8uaeuc4cexxxxxxxxv3ha1r50e.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxxxxx&grant_type=authorization_code
```

i got following response:

```
An error occured connecting to the server: 400 returned.

<TITLE>Required parameter is missing: grant_type</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Required parameter is missing: grant_type</H1> <H2>Error 400</H2>
```

Any one help me to get accesstoken

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the slash shouldn't be there in your *code* parameter. If needed it should be url encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The format that Google shared these code keys is like the one given in the example. I do not believe your problem is because any of the credentials. I highly recommend to visit http://www.visualab.org/index.php/using-google-rest-api-for-analytics  and I assure you will be fine. Also do not forget these tokens expires in 3600 seconds so have to whether reload the key approval screen for requesting new 'code' or follow the instructions in the link and understand 'refresh token' 'access token' for further lines of codes.